# "Program File does not exist" while trying to debug with Eclipse/OpenOCD

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, openocd, nrf51

I recently got a nrf51 bluetooth module and I am trying to debug it with Eclipse Mars. I installed the required toolchain as well as OpenOCD (I am using STLink v2 to debug the board).

While running openOCD and arm-none-eabi-gdb in console, everything works fine. The OpenOCD server starts up and I am able to connect with the gdb tool.

However, when trying to start a debug session with Eclipse, it throws the error "Exception occurred during launch. Reason: Program file does not exist". The build process finishes normally. It's the first time I used Eclipse for C/C++ development and the first time after years I used Eclipse at all so I don't even have an idea what could be wrong.

I tried messing around with the project settings without luck. Can anyone give me a hint?

I should mention, I used an already existing Makefile since I tried compiling one of the nordic SDK examples. I Changed it so the resulting files are ready for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In past I've used [Segger's Jlink](https://www.segger.com/jlink-debug-probes.html) programmer and the JlinkExe (A pre-built binary) for Linux platform to program Nordic Bluetooth module such as NRF51 and it worked seamlessly. There are some very good documentation on using [GNU toolchain with NRF51](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/18/development-with-eclipse-and-gcc/) series SOC and in case you get your hands on Segger's Jlink, I would recommend you to use that for programming. Meanwhile, this [thread](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/37164/programming-nrf51822-with-openocd-and-stlink-v2-issues/) in the Nordic's developer zone seem to be very much similar to your problem. Maybe you'll be find some clues there.